# How to check if an OpenGL texture name is valid

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have an Android application and, under certain situations, some, but not all, of our textures seem to become unbound.  (That is, when I use glBindTexture and draw it, it is rendered as a blank texture)

I've tried looking for an error from glBindTexture, and tried using glGet with GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D, but nothing has helped thus far.

Is there any way to discover if a texture name is still valid/pointing to valid data?

My last resort is to save some small amount of pixel data and then, when these events happen, bind and use glReadPixels and see if they're still there...  But that seems really... non-optimal...

This is OpenGL ES 1.0/1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [glIsTexture](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glIsTexture.xml) is what you're looking for.

Comment: I think this is the answer, but it seems my problem is worse off. glIsTexture returns true, but the actual fragment data is totally borked. =/

Answer (score 1):

glIsTexture is not valid reply to this question. glIsTexture is returning true even if the texture name is not valid. This is a problem of Android implementation of OpenGL. I have no solution to this.